# Google Maps Flash API: Adjust size to stage

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, google-maps

I want to set the map's size to the container's size, automatically. I'm using:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeListener); 
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

function resizeListener (e:Event):void { 
    map.setSize(new Point(stage.width, stage.height));
}
```

When the Flash movie begins, I do

```
map.setSize(new Point(stage.width, stage.height));
```

on the map initialization.

I'm using version 1.20 of the SWC component on Flash CS5 and AS3. However, when I compile the SWF, the player crashes.

I've seen that with v1.8 of the API you can resize the map to the stage size with no problem.

Has anyone encountered this before?
Any thoughts on a solution?

*Solution*

Use `stage.stageWidth` and `stage.stageHeight`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things:

1. *width* and *height* are override properties of the Stage.  you want to write `stage.stageWidth` and `stage.stageHeight`.
2. i don't understand why Google wrote their *setSize()* method to accept a Point object.  it's confusing and ghetto.  why not just 2 required Number parameters?  /rant.  anyway, you can alternatively set the width and height of the map object by assigning values to those properties (`map.width` and `map.height`) if you don't want to use their not-so-convenient *setSize()* method.